# Use of \lowercase

Tags: capitalization

If I write:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\lowercase{Norma}
\end{document}
```

I get "norma" in the output, lowercased as I want it. However, if I write:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\expandafter\def\csname mw@mu\endcsname{Norma}

\begin{document}
\lowercase{\csname mw@mu\endcsname}
\end{document}
```

I get "Norma", with the capital letter, which I don't want. I tried putting `\noexpand` before `\lowercase`, and surrounding `\lowercase` with `\expandafter`s, but to no avail: the capital letter is always there. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands `\lowercase` and `\uppercase` don't expand their contents; they just convert character tokens in their argument and put back the token list in the input stream.

In your code, what's subject to possible case change are `m` `w` `@` `m` and `u`; indeed, if you try

```
\lowercase{\csname MW@MU\endcsname}
```

you'll get the same result as

```
\lowercase{\csname mw@mu\endcsname}
```

Just to make the example simpler:

```
\def\Norma{Norma}
\lowercase{\Norma}
```

will print

> Norma

because symbolic tokens are not touched by `\lowercase`. If you really want to lowercase the expansion of `\Norma` you have to say

```
\lowercase\expandafter{\Norma}
```

but just the first token will be expanded, not other tokens following it. For the macro given with `\csname` you need

```
\lowercase\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname mw@mu\endcsname}
```

Comment: I see. Now it works. Thanks. Is there by any chance a LaTeX3 version of `\lowercase` that _does_ expand its argument? Is there a way to generate one?

Comment: @MickG `\begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup\protect\MakeLowercase{<code>}}\x` will do.