# includegraphic with filename variable to lowercase

Tags: graphics, scrlttr2

I have the following code that works fine, but would like to make it to lowercase which I have not quiet accomplished yet

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkomavar{fromname}{t}

\def\mylogo{class_\csname scr@fromname@var\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{\mylogo}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how I could make sure that whatever is in the komavar is in lowercase?

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate?): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204541/use-of-lowercase

Comment: @Marijn it is related but I cannot just sub ```\lowercase\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname scr@fromname@var\endcsname}``` for ```\csname ...\endcsname```. Do I need more ```\expandafter``` or is there another way?

Comment: There is another way, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173481/expandably-change-letter-case-and-use-inside-csname-without-a-package. I tried `\setkomavar{fromname}{B}\usepackage{stringstrings}\caselower[q]{\csname scr@fromname@var\endcsname}\def\mylogolc{example-image-\thestring}` and that works for your code as well (generating the filename `example-image-b`, which is a special demo image file that is part of the `graphicx` package).

Comment: @Marijn Thanks that works for me!